# Using laser_scan_matcher output

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to have a confirmation on my understanding in order to use the output of `laser_scan_matcher(lsm)` in a correct way. Kindly refer to the provided figure(sorry for providing a mere sketch). For convention, please assume any subscript of 1 refers to the previous data(means x1= previous x value from `lsm` and so on). Likewise, subscript of 2 refers to the current data. P1 and P2 is the position of the x and y values returned by pose2D of the previous and current values respectively that have been mapped into a `cartesian` coordinate.

My questions are:

1. Is that correct the representation of variables in the context of `lsm`?
2. Calculation of Q:

i) Either:

```
    Q = sqrt[(x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²] x sin(theta1)  OR 
    Q = sqrt[(x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²] x sin(theta2) OR
    Q = sqrt[(x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²] x sin(theta2-theta1)
```

ii) OR Q = x2-x1

This sounds like a fundamental math problem, but with respect to the values returned by `lsm` makes me confused. Perhaps someone who is experienced using the package or preferably the author himself can give some comments regarding this.

In my opinion, the correct one should be Q = sqrt[(x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²] x sin(theta1), but I don't know if this one is correct or not in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

[image: image description]

EDIT:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28781/using-laser_scan_matcher-output/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Yes, that is a correct interpretation of the output.
2. The way you have drawn the figure, Q is equal to (y2 - y1), or the *change of the y component of the robot frame with respect to the fixed frame*

What is Q, in the context of your application?

Also, this is not really related to laser_scan_matcher, but looks more like a general trigonometry question, or at best a question on robot motion models. Maybe this [reference](http://honnunx.googlecode.com/files/Kinematics.pdf) would be useful.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-29**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: I doubt about what I've represented regarding the theta from "lsm" in the drawn image is right. Could it be the case, like I edited in the figure? I mean, the theta is the angle how much it rotates after it translates. The black part of the robot, say, its front.